# Alternative way mysql nested query in procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery

Any recommendation for mysql nested query in procedure?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_PLACE_PARENT_CATEGORY`(IN paramCategoryId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT pc.place_parent_category_id, (SELECT pcc.place_category FROM place_category  pcc WHERE pcc.place_category_id = pc.place_parent_category_id )
FROM place_category pc WHERE pc.place_category_id = paramCategoryId;
END
```

Comment: Rewrite the query with a proper [join.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your nested query is on the same table. You sure this is correct ?
I believe you want a simple join between 2 tables. Something like this maybe :

SELECT pc.place_parent_category_id, pcc.place_category
FROM place_category pc 
left join place_parent_category as pcc on pcc.place_category_id = pc.place_parent_category_id
WHERE pc.place_parent_category_id = paramCategoryId;

Comment: Which is efficient way? Mine or yours?

Comment: See for yourself, do a EXPLAIN in front of both queries
http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/timing-your-sql-queries-2010-07-07/